# Why is this simple Sklearn SVM off?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, svm

I've been looking at the theory of Linear SVM and there's an easy-to-use one in Python Scikitlearn... For a hypothetical example, let's say that a serving of coffee is gross by itself - as is a cup of cream, naturally. Adding Cream+sugary coffee seems to be quite popular though as evidenced by all the drive thru cafe shops. So this should naturally result in an easy chart with line between the (0,1) and (1,0), separating the good value (1,1)... but the result is inaccurate for this simple example:

```
from __future__ import division
# data points [coffee, cream]:
data = [[ 0,0 ], [ 0,1 ], [ 1,0 ], [ 1,1 ] ]

#Just last one is a positive experience
category = [ -1,  -1,  -1, 1 ]

import numpy
from sklearn.svm import SVC

clf = SVC(kernel='linear')
clf.fit(data, category)

#Get m coefficients:
coef = clf.coef_[0]
b = clf.intercept_[0]

print('This is the M*X+b=0 equation...')
print('M=%s' % (coef))
print('b=%s' % (b))
print('So the equation of the separating line in this 2d svm is:')
print('%f*x + %f*y + %f = 0' % (coef[0],coef[1],b))
print('The support vector limit lines are:')
print('%f*x + %f*y + %f = -1' % (coef[0],coef[1],b))
print('%f*x + %f*y + %f = 1' % (coef[0],coef[1],b))

vertmatrix = [[x] for x in coef]

good = 0
bad = 0
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    #i-th element, d in data:
    calculatedValue = numpy.dot(d, vertmatrix)[0] + b
    print( 'Mx+b for x=%s calculates to %s' % (d, calculatedValue) )
    if calculatedValue > 0 and category[i] > 0:
        good += 1
    elif calculatedValue < 0 and category[i] < 0:
        good += 1
    else:
        bad +=1 #they should have matched category.

print('accuracy=%f' % (good/(good+bad)) )
#The same as the builtin "score" accuracy:
print('accuracy=%f' % clf.score(data, category) )
```

Comment: The current data is imbalanced. It has 75% of one class. So you need to tweak the hyperparameters to adjust to this problem. Maybe just use `class_weight` like this:  `clf = SVC(kernel='linear',class_weight={-1:1, 1:2})`

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is just to add more data. Without changing anything in the algorithm you can get better result:

```
# data points [coffee, cream]:
data = [[ 0,0 ], [ 0,1 ], [ 1,0 ], [ 1,1 ] ] *5 # 5 times more data

#Just last one is a positive experience
category = [ -1,  -1,  -1, 1 ] * 5
```

The output will be:

```
This is the M*X+b=0 equation...
M=[ 2.  2.]
b=-3.0
So the equation of the separating line in this 2d svm is:
2.000000*x + 2.000000*y + -3.000000 = 0
The support vector limit lines are:
2.000000*x + 2.000000*y + -3.000000 = -1
2.000000*x + 2.000000*y + -3.000000 = 1
Mx+b for x=[0, 0] calculates to -3.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 1] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 0] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 1] calculates to 1.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 0] calculates to -3.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 1] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 0] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 1] calculates to 1.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 0] calculates to -3.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 1] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 0] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 1] calculates to 1.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 0] calculates to -3.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 1] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 0] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 1] calculates to 1.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 0] calculates to -3.0
Mx+b for x=[0, 1] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 0] calculates to -1.0
Mx+b for x=[1, 1] calculates to 1.0
accuracy=1.000000
accuracy=1.000000
```

Comment: Why is this even works? Same data with no extra discrimination value and make a difference? Can you explain a bit?

Comment: I noticed that too, at least, adding a [1.01, 1,01] that is positive, makes it 100% accuracy. Can you hint as to what that does mathematically?

Comment: Adding `[1.01, 1.01]` is another different sample though. It's totally different.

Comment: For an explanation why this works: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323191/adding-data-to-change-svm-classification/323211

Answer (score 1):

You should play a bit with the parameters (C in that case for example) and not take just the default (`C=1`) since it could not be adequate for every problem:

```
C_values = [1e-4, 1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]
for C in C_values:
    clf = SVC(kernel='linear', C=C)
    clf.fit(data, category)
    print('For C = {} results = {}'.format(C, clf.predict(data)))
```

You will see that after some point it separates data correctly.

> For C = 0.0001 results = [0 0 0 0]
>
> For C = 0.001 results = [0 0 0 0]
>
> For C = 0.01 results = [0 0 0 0]
>
> For C = 0.1 results = [0 0 0 0]
>
> For C = 1 results = [0 0 0 0]
>
> For C = 10 results = [0 0 0 1]
>
> For C = 100 results = [0 0 0 1]
>
> For C = 1000 results = [0 0 0 1]

Edit:

In a response to @AndreyF answer for which I could not even understand (as I stated in comments) why it worked I asked a question to Cross Validated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323191/adding-data-to-change-svm-classification/323211).

To summarize here what I understood is that the parameter `C` in the soft margin solution expresses how much it will take into consideration each sample. So, when just a sample is misclassified (as in the above case) it does not pay much attention (or the penalty for this misclassification is quite small). When the number of samples increases so does the penalty and that means they are taken into much more consideration.

It's equivalent to increasing the parameter `C` but in my opinion manipulating `C` is more theory consistent.

Comment: "Setting C: C is 1 by default and it’s a reasonable default choice. If you have a lot of noisy observations you should decrease it. It corresponds to regularize more the estimation." - so in this case it's the opposite, that makes sense... http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-classification